# How to return coroutine or dict(some object)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have to methods with exactly the same logic. The only difference is that it returns different values.

```
async def job_pooling(self):
    message['status'] = Text.NEW.value
    await self.db.store_alert(..)
    await self.aws.delete_message(..)
    yield message


async def job_pooling(self):
    message['status'] = Comment.NEW.value
    store_message = await self.db.store_comment(..)
    await self.aws.delete_message(..)
    yield store_message
```

How to generalize it?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? It would also be helpful if you provided a dependency-free version of your functions. That would make it much easier to generalize for other use cases. :)

Comment: @MSeifert I mean `coroutine is not None` it's `true` and `dict is not None` it's true, so I always return `yield store_item`

Comment: @MSeifert update question

Comment: Do you use Python 3.6? Why do you use `yield`? Async generator that yields one value - is what you want?

Comment: `print(type(await self.db.store_alert(message)))`  will print `coroutine`? If so, you should probably rewrite `store_alert`: coroutine on awaiting should return value, not another coroutine.

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail yes, I use python3.6

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail `self.db.store_alert(message)` just put some message to db: `await self._save(item=item, table=self.alert_table)`, but `await self.db.store_comment(message)` put some message to the db and the return parsed message: `await self._save(item=item, table=self.comment_table) return _parse_one_comment(item)`

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail my question is how to combine this two behaviour in one method `generic_background_job_pooling`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to "generalize" this ? These two functions _look_ globally similar but as far as I'm concerned there are enough differences in the functions flow (specially on what they return) to warrant distinct functions. If and when you find yourself with 3 ore more functions with _exactly_ the same logic and only different types involved it will be time to refactor them, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know type of `store_item` result, you can use it instead of comparing to `None`:

```
async def job_pooling(sqs_in, status, store_item, delete_message):
    message['status'] = status.NEW.value
    item = await store_item(message)
    await delete_message(message=message, sqs_url=sqs_in)
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        yield item
    yield message
```